# JuiceUI component not saving viewstate

Tags: user-interface, datepicker, postback, viewstate, juice-ui

When using the DatePicker JuiceUI control the text field used to store the value does not retain its value upon postback. The DatePicker control is set as follows;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_DueDate" Type="date" MaxLength="50" CssClass="requiredField" Width="75" runat="server" />
<Juice:Datepicker ID="dp_DueDate" TargetControlID="txt_DueDate" ButtonImage="/images/signs/ico_calendar.gif" DateFormat="dd/mm/yy" ButtonImageOnly="true" ShowOn="both" ButtonText="Select date" runat="server" />
```

Apart from adding the DatePicker control and the Type="date" attribute to the text box, this text box stored the value from a previous javascript only date picker and maintained it's value after postback.

Is there a attribute I am missing on either of these controls to make viewstate work again?

Answer (score 3):

I tested the code you provided in a new page with a single button and the textbox retained the value set by the datepicker on postback initiated by an asp:button. There must be something else in your code resetting the value of the textbox.

Comment: Yeah I just tried a new date picker and experienced the same issue. I don't know why I would be clearing date boxes like that but it is 6 yr old code so I guess I need to refresh my memory a little more ;) thx for testing that out.